# How to set up the color table for QGIS (Python) raster layer

Tags: gdal, qgis-3

I'm trying to plot a matrix data (1500 x 1500) as a colored raster layer on QGIS-3. As the original values of the matrix are floating point numbers, the matrix is rescaled and the code snippet looks like:

```
        data = ma.getdata(data)
        data_scaled =  np.interp(data, (data.min(), data.max()), (0, 255))
        data_scaled2 = data_scaled.astype(int)
        pigmentum = gdal.ColorTable()
        pigmentum.CreateColorRamp(0,(0,0,0),255,(255,0,0))
        band.SetColorTable(pigmentum)
        band.WriteArray(data_scaled2)
```

However, this is signaling the error SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format. I checked and data_scaled2 ranges between 0 & 255. [Note: Because UInt16 is supposed to go up to 65535, I tried switching the maximum range from 255 to 65535 but got the same error message].